# Where are the popcorn time temporary files stored on OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos, torrent

I want to find the location of temporary files created by popcorn time so that I can stream via the chromecast player to my TV. I can find that on Windows but don't know where  is it located on Mac.

Comment: Did you check ~/Library already?

Comment: @Rob ~/Library contains hundreds of files and folders—can you be any more specific?

Answer (score 44):

With Popcorn Time for MacOS, version 6.2.1.17, the videos are stored in ~/Downloads/PopcornTime by default.

In Settings -> Download, there is an option to choose your own place for it. Next to it is a blue link to "Open folder", which brings up a Finder window.

Comment: The new syntax is `open $TMPDIR/Butter`

Comment: currently it is open $TMPDIR/Popcorn-Time-CE-cache/

Comment: Try ~/Downloads/PopcornTime/ ?

Answer (score 8):

In the Popcorn Time program, click the settings Cog in the top right corner to open the settings page.
At the top of the SETTINGS page, checkmark SHOW ADVANCED SETTINGS. 
Scroll down to CACHE DIRECTORY settings.
The default setting is to clear the cache folder when you close the program. 
Uncheck this option so that the movies you watch will stay in the temporary folder. You can click the folder icon next to the cache filename path to open the Temporary PopcornTime folder in Finder.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in the latest version installed today (10/8/14, not sure how to tell version from app) there is a "PopcornTime" folder in your "Downloads" folder.

Answer (score 1):

Folder name changed, use:

open $TMPDIR/Butter

Comment: That should be an edit to http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/132301/237 quoting documentation of the change

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting you.  Until the old answer has an edit that's accepted this is the new correct answer.

Answer (score -4):

Start a Terminal and use

```
find / -name filename.abc
```

`find` is a unix command with a large set of options but basically it is `find [path...] [expression]`. If you search the whole filesystem `/` you will get permission errors, use

```
sudo find / -name filename.abc
```

to avoid this. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) is its manpage.

Comment: this is not the anser to the question, this is a gnu util explained but does not tell the OP where to look.